# Web Query code is running slowly

Tags: excel, vba

I am fetching currency rate through a web query. The issue i am facing is that if i want to run the loop more then 20 time then it gets hanged as i am new to VBA so i required some assistance how to improve the execution speed.
Below is my code.

```
Sub CurrencyConvert()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim Fcurrency As String, Scurrency As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Static k As Integer

    Worksheets.Add.Name = "Temp"

    k = First.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = k + 1 To k + 16
        Fcurrency = First.Cells(i, 1)
        Scurrency = First.Cells(i, 2)
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
          "URL;http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=" & Fcurrency & "&To=" & Scurrency, _
          Destination:=Worksheets("Temp").Range("$A$1"))
            .Name = "?Amount=1&From=" & Fcurrency & "&To=" & Scurrency
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With

        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 4) = VBA.Left(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 3), VBA.InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 3), " "))
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 4).Copy First.Cells(i, 3)

        Worksheets("Temp").UsedRange.Clear
        First.Cells(1, 5) = "Total Converted:-" & k
    Next i

    Worksheets("Temp").Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

This is the format of my sheet.

```
CUR1   CUR2   Current Rates
USD    USD    1
USD    INR    61.9169
USD    GBP    0.604447
USD    EUR    0.721379
USD    AED    3.6728
USD    JOD    0.7079
USD    MXN    13.1101
USD    ARS    6.473
```

Comment: Adding a `DoEvents` just before `Next i` will stop the code from apearing to "hang" (it won't do anything for the speed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are running a query to the server for every single row.
There is a lot of overhead in a new query, and for a relatively small amount of information (20 rows or so) you should probably run a query that includes ALL the exchange rates, and use a recordset object to iterate through each rate, THEN output to excel after.

Comment: On top of that, you could use a ADODB connection object which will help as well.